# how to copy to clipboard text between h2 tags in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

what i try to do here is get email code for verification. so I log in to the email, select and copy the 6 digits code from the email and paste it to the other tab. everything is done except i can not double click to select the 6 digit code and copy it to clipboard. the code is between h2 tag and nothing else, like this: 639094 where 639094 is actually the code which i need to be copied. how can i find the code element or whatever and copy it? here is a screen shot of the email and the chrome inspect element if anything helps.

this is the code that I use to copy the code:

```
codeID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
'//table[@class="main"]//tr//td//p//h2').text

ActionChains = ActionChains(driver)
ActionChains.double_click(codeID).perform()
time.sleep(2)
codeID.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c')
text = pyperclip.paste()
print(text)
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik7cS.png)

Comment: I think what you need is `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` and full xpath of text, for full xpath you can right click on code in google chrome, select the `h2` element -> copy -> full xpath.

Answer (score 1):

element is found however looks like can not be copied. the error is Element  is not reachable by keyboard. if i do everything automatically up until the element is selected with double click and copy the element with my actual keyboard the element is copied, however when selenium try to copy i get the error from above. the code i use to double click the element is:

```
codeID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="message-htmlpart1"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/h2')
ActionChains = ActionChains(driver)
ActionChains.double_click(codeID).perform()
time.sleep(2)
```

and to do the copy is :

```
codeID.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c')
text = pyperclip.paste()
print(text)
```

this is the part where the error ocur:

```
codeID.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c')
text = pyperclip.paste()
print(text)
```

for some reason it says "Element  is not reachable by keyboard" but the element/code numbers are selected.

if I use print(text) they are also printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="main"]//tr//td//h2').text` this will give you the text/code

[image]

Comment: not working, i get the error:

Selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //table[@class="main"]//tr//td//p//h2

Comment: Can you share the full html ?? I think it's in a iframe because I have checked my  roundcube mail. The email stays inside a iframe in that case you need to use ` iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe) ` then try the xpath

Comment: here https://pastebin.com/txBSc8UZ

Comment: updated the code try  again

Comment: thanks, now the code is opened, selected with double click but when try to copy i get error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <h2> is not reachable by keyboard

so basically the code is working until this part:

    codeID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@class="main"]//tr//td//h2')
    ActionChains = ActionChains(driver)
   ActionChains.double_click(codeID).perform()

but this part is not working and showing the error:

    codeID.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c')

with other elements is working fine, if anything helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i will analyse this problem with you
For the first part :

- try to take that XPath you have and past it in the Xpath helper (google chrome extension)
  => If you find that element , than the problem in your code
  => if you don’t than the element is already in a frame or in a table
  The solution is to change your drive to the new frame and relocate the element inside the frame
  Exemple :

iframe_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe')

driver.switch_to.frame('iframe_xpath')
Now try to relocate the element starting from the iframe

For the second part :
You say it’s a table so you need to mention the /td[i] and /tr[j] value where the number is located so you can get it
Exemple

```
d = driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//tr[i]/td[j]").text
```

I hope that’s help

Comment: nope, please check my second answer because i did not know how to put it in a comment.

Comment: Could you share all the page path so i can understand more what we have

Comment: sorry but i can't it's an email.